# Need toggle button to show the 2 states in fredhq 's Roundabout jQuery plug-in

Tags: jquery, button, 3d, toggle, carousel

I am using the 3D image carousel [Roundabout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) jQuery plugin by Fred LeBlanc.

I forked a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/positive_x/9wTPZ/) that has control buttons;

the  JS code for using the play / pause control

```
 btnToggleAutoplay: ".toggle",
```

and the html essentially is

```
<a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a>
```

. It funcions by picking the button to pause the automatic animation , then pick again to re-start.

What is needed is to have the **button show the 2 different 'toggle' states** , which is presently beyond this cut-n-paste~coder.

The documentation lists both 
 "*Callable Methods*"  http: / / fredhq . com / projects / roundabout / #isAutoplaying

```
.roundabout("isAutoplaying")
```

Returns a boolean

, and  "*Hookable Events*" http: / / fredhq . com / projects / roundabout / #autoplayStart

autoplayStart

This event fires on the Roundabout element when the autoplay feature starts.

autoplayStop

This event fires on the Roundabout element when the autoplay feature stops.

The method to implement either of these api methods is unkown to me personally. Please help a green-horn.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just add a `.click` to your "toggle button" that checks the current button text and changes it. Assuming I understand that you want it to say "Pause" while playing and "Play" while paused, I have a working JSFiddle.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9wTPZ/9/)

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    var button = $(this);

    if(button.html() == 'Play') {
        button.html('Pause');//Playing, click to pause
    } else {
        button.html('Play');//Paused, click to play
    }   
});
```

EDIT: To change the CSS, you can just use the `.css()` function.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9wTPZ/10/)

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    var button = $(this);

    if(button.hasClass('gray')) {
        //button.html('Pause');//Playing, click to pause
        button.removeClass('gray');
        button.addClass('blue');
        button.css('backgroundColor', 'rgb(33, 121, 182)');
    } else {
        //button.html('Play');//Paused, click to play        
        button.removeClass('blue');
        button.addClass('gray');
        button.css('backgroundColor', '#2f2f2f');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; however , I am planning on using a bullet symbol html: `&bull;` with css: `border:ridge #0c0c0c; background-color: #2f2f2f;`. How do I change the css ?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you can modify the CSS through JQuery's `.css()` function. I hope that helps you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks again for the very-quick answers. However , I noticed that this jQuery plug-in has an option enabled that pauses the animation on hover -ing over it , and that both of the proposed answers do not take this into account.